# fix date with JavaScript date()

Tags: javascript

I am writing a blog, and I want to use the time that each blog post was created as the time posted. How can I use Javascript date(), and keep the date the same after a period of time?

Comment: You don't.
You need to save the date on the server side in the database, along with the blog title, content etc.

Comment: Would this be possible via Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

This is done server-side, not client side. Javascript date() function is done on the client/browser. So, if somebody changes the time on the machine, the date() function returns a different date. If the date is wrong on the machine, the date() function returns the wrong date. So, normally, for blog posts, dates are stored on database. If you use wordpress or other cms systems, the implementation details would already be covered, so, you don't have to worry about the implementation details